# iOS : How to observe the result of "respondToRequest:withResult" in CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have been using CoreBlueTooth framework to communicate between BTLE iOS devices.On the Peripheral side, I received a writing request from Central:

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests{
            ...
}
```

According to Apple's doc on CoreBluetooth, I answered with:

```
[self.peripheralManager respondToRequest:request  withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];
```

However, this method does not have a return value or delegate methods to indicate the result.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on the documentation provided by Apple about Bluetooth feature

[Apple's Bluetooth DOC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

`respondToRequest:withResult:` method is assumed to always successful. You must observe it on Central side at HCI level (probably using `hcidump` command or `btmon` if you use linux).

Comment: It is definitely possible that the response is lost due to buffer cap in the Core Bluetooth stack or similar. A recent SO question revealed this issue. When it happens, it causes the connection to be automatically broken in 30 seconds. An indicator for such event is when the `updateValue:ForCharacteristic` returns false.

Comment: @allprog and if it lost, what what happen next?

Comment: @gaussblurinc I'm not sure I get your question. I think I described the "when lost" case in my comment. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: @allprog sure, you said: "response is lost due to buffer cap in CB stack or similar." and "updateValue:ForCharacteristic returns false".it returns false only if peripheral update its value, not central write to peripheral. could this case causes ( sometimes ) nil CBAttrRequest in didReceive methods?

Comment: @gaussblurinc I haven't seen this but if you can reliably reproduce this event, then probably this is what happens. Unfortunately, I can't confirm or disprove. If you think it's a bug, you should file a RDAR and it would be great if you shared it on the bluetooth-dev mailing list too.